# Unable to switch hw keyboard language

Tags: keyboard, languages, external-keyboard

Do I have to buy HW keyboard located to my native language in order to be able to write in my native languag ?

So far, everytime I connect HW keyboard which has natively only EN characters, I am not able to write interpunctions and any special characters of my native language, despite Android shows that my native language is choosen.

I've used stock (LG keyboard), gboard, swiftkey

nothing helped, once HW keyboard is connected, only English and characters which are on the keyboard physically marked, I can use.

Thank you

Comment: An USB keyboard is language independent (except for it's key printings), it simply sends keycodes of pressed keys. What character is assigned to each key only the OS knows which processes the keycodes.

Comment: So, it simply doesn't work. Shame